# how to change stroke value in nuke roto node?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I didn't find anything related to that in the docs.

```
n = nuke.selectedNode()
if n.Class() == "Roto":
   print n.name
```

Comment: I think you'll probably need to provide more context for anyone to be able to properly help you.

Comment: already tried all social media. but i can't get correct answer :-(

Comment: You've barely described your problem. How do you expect anyone to help you?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean values under the Stroke tab?
Those are only available on the RotoPaint node, not the Roto node.
You can set them when using Brush/Cloning/Smear etc but not on roto curves

```
n = nuke.selectedNode()
n['brush_size'].setValue(10)
```

[RotoPaint vs Roto](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9aFaN.png)

Answer (score 0):

```
node = nuke.selectedNode()
curves=node["curves"]
brush=curves.toElement('Brush1')
attrs = brush.getAttributes()
attrs.set("bs",20)
```